# What's the difference between fill_parent and wrap_content?

Tags: android, layout, user-interface

In Android, when layout out widgets, what's the difference between `fill_parent` (`match_parent` in API Level 8 and higher) and `wrap_content`?

Is there any documentation where you can point to? I'm interested in understanding it very well.

Comment: Take note that the `fill_parent` was renamed `match_parent` in API Level 8 and higher.

Answer (score 277, accepted):

Either attribute can be applied to View's (visual control) horizontal or vertical size. It's used to set a View or Layouts size based on either it's contents or the size of it's parent layout rather than explicitly specifying a dimension.

**`fill_parent`** (deprecated and renamed `MATCH_PARENT` in API Level 8 and higher)

Setting the layout of a widget to fill_parent will force it to expand to take up as much space as is available within the layout element it's been placed in. It's roughly equivalent of setting the dockstyle of a Windows Form Control to `Fill`.

Setting a top level layout or control to fill_parent will force it to take up the whole screen.

**`wrap_content`**

Setting a View's size to wrap_content will force it to expand only far enough to contain the values (or child controls) it contains. For controls -- like text boxes (TextView) or images (ImageView) -- this will wrap the text or image being shown. For layout elements it will resize the layout to fit the controls / layouts added as its children.

It's roughly the equivalent of setting a Windows Form Control's `Autosize` property to True.

**Online Documentation**

There's some details in the Android code documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html).

Comment: what if image width is bigger than screen width and I set imageview width as fill_parent. will the image be compressed to screen size ?

Comment: @JohnWatson did you find your answer? I'm curious as well.

Comment: It's good to know the equivalent properties of Windows Form Control that are mentioned.

Comment: What have you seen @JohnWatson ? What is your story ? What is the answer ?

Answer (score 41):

**`fill_parent`** (deprecated) **= `match_parent`**
The border of the child view expands to match the border of the parent view.

**`wrap_content`**
The border of the child view wraps snugly around its own content.

Here are some images to make things more clear. The green and red are `TextViews`. The white is a `LinearLayout` showing through.

[image]

Every `View` (a `TextView`, an `ImageView`, a `Button`, etc.) needs to set the `width` and the `height` of the view. In the xml layout file, that might look like this:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Besides setting the width and height to `match_parent` or `wrap_content`, you could also set them to some absolute value:

```
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="200dp"
```

Generally that is not as good, though, because it is not as flexible for different sized devices. After you have understood `wrap_content` and `match_parent`, the next thing to learn is `layout_weight`.

## See also

- [What does android:layout_weight mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29713797/3681880)
- [Difference between a View's Padding and Margin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25520320/3681880)
- [Gravity vs layout_gravity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26190050/3681880)

## XML for above images

Vertical LinearLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="width=wrap height=wrap"
        android:background="#c5e1b0"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="width=match height=wrap"
        android:background="#f6c0c0"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="width=match height=match"
        android:background="#c5e1b0"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Horizontal LinearLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="WrapWrap"
        android:background="#c5e1b0"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="WrapMatch"
        android:background="#f6c0c0"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="MatchMatch"
        android:background="#c5e1b0"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

## Note

The explanation in this answer assumes there is no [margin or padding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25520320/3681880). But even if there is, the basic concept is still the same. The view border/spacing is just adjusted by the value of the margin or padding.

Answer (score 14):

- `fill_parent` will make the width or height of the element to be as
  large as the parent element, in other words, the container.
- `wrap_content` will make the width or height be as large as needed to
  contain the elements within it.

[Click here for ANDROID DOC Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html)

Comment: what will be the container? how to surround the views with different containers?

Answer (score 3):

**`fill_parent`** :

A component is arranged layout for the `fill_parent` will be mandatory to expand to fill the layout unit members, as much as possible in the space. This is consistent with the dockstyle property of the Windows control. A top set layout or control to `fill_parent` will force it to take up the entire screen.

**`wrap_content`**

Set up a view of the size of `wrap_content` will be forced to view is expanded to show all the content. The **TextView and ImageView** controls, for example, is set to `wrap_content` will display its entire internal text and image. Layout elements will change the size according to the content. Set up a view of the size of Autosize attribute `wrap_content` roughly equivalent to set a Windows control for True.

For details Please Check out this link : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html