# What does android:layout_weight mean?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I don't understand how to use this attribute. Can anyone tell me more about it?

Answer (score 906, accepted):

With `layout_weight` you can specify a size ratio between multiple views. E.g. you have a `MapView` and a `table` which should show some additional information to the map. The map should use 3/4 of the screen and table should use 1/4 of the screen. Then you will set the `layout_weight` of the `map` to 3 and the `layout_weight` of the `table` to 1.

To get it work you also have to set the height or width (depending on your orientation) to 0px.

Comment: head scratcher until you mentioned the 0px height!

Comment: To define which of them will be affected by weight. Width or height.

Comment: You do need the 0px.  Example: you want to implement a table with two equally-sized columns.  Each table row is a horizontal linear layout with two "table cells" (for example, TextViews), each one having layout_weight=.5.  If you specify layout_width="wrap_content" on the "table cells," the content width will be added to the width calculated by layout_weight, the table cells will be all different sizes, and the columns won't line up correctly.  So you have to set layout_width=0dp so that android only uses layout_weight to calculate the width of the cells.

Comment: What if the parent is a `RelativeLayout`, will it act on width or height, which one needs to be set to `0px`?

Comment: You don't need the `0px` in a child of `LinearLayout` because the `android:orientation` attribute specifies the whether the items are arranged vertically or horizontally.

Comment: 0px on height or width (while using `layout_weight`) does not work for buttons. It makes them disappear.

Comment: @Solace, late answer, but for completeness sake ..  Seems like weight attribute is not contributing to RelativeLayout. It only works with LinearLayout. If you see a need for weigth, perhaps the way to go is to create a LinearLayout (with weightages) within RelativeLayout.

Comment: Also ..Maybe For beginners....If Layout has multiple children's ,then do not forget to give layout_weight to each and every view.

Comment: I used this inside a horizontal `RadioGroup` with two `RadioButton`s inside a `RelativeLayout`. Setting the first wieght to 1 and the second to 3 gave me a nice margin between the first and second.

Comment: if you include the layout_weight attribute then the system has to calculate the width (or height) a second time, using the weight value to allocate space. It’s twice the work. This is why you should set the width or height attribute value to 0dp so there’s no extra calculation. The system then uses the weight attribute to do the calculation.

Comment: The very same explanation holds for GridLayout - if you want to stretch in both directions both of them needs the 0dp!

Comment: For a better understanding, you can imagine the distribution in percent.
Means you have e.g. 3 buttons, one of them takes half of the screen, the other two fill the second half.
Then you can set the weights like this: `50, 25, 25`

Answer (score 267):

In a nutshell, **`layout_weight` specifies how much of the extra space in the layout to be allocated to the View.**

LinearLayout supports assigning a weight to individual children. This attribute assigns an "importance" value to a view, and allows it to expand to fill any remaining space in the parent view. Views' default weight is zero.

## Calculation to assign any remaining space between child

In general, the formula is:

> space assigned to child = (child's individual weight) / (sum of weight of every child in Linear Layout)

### Example 1

If there are three text boxes and two of them declare a weight of 1, while the third one is given no weight (0), then remaining space is assigned as follows:

> 1st text box = 1/(1+1+0)
>
> 2nd text box = 1/(1+1+0)
>
> 3rd text box = 0/(1+1+0)

### Example 2

Let's say we have a text label and two text edit elements in a horizontal row. The label has no `layout_weight` specified, so it takes up the minimum space required to render. If the `layout_weight` of each of the two text edit elements is set to 1, the remaining width in the parent layout will be split equally between them (because we claim they are equally important).

Calculation:

> 1st label = 0/(0+1+1)
>
> 2nd text box = 1/(0+1+1)
>
> 3rd text box = 1/(0+1+1)

If, instead, the first one text box has a `layout_weight` of 1, and the second text box has a `layout_weight` of 2, then one third of the remaining space will be given to the first, and two thirds to the second (because we claim the second one is more important).

Calculation:

> 1st label = 0/(0+1+2)
>
> 2nd text box = 1/(0+1+2)
>
> 3rd text box = 2/(0+1+2)

---

[Source article](https://web.archive.org/web/20190725014852/http://www.anddev.org/view-layout-resource-problems-f27/what-does-android-layout-weight-0-mean-t376.html)

Comment: A much better explanation than the currently selected answer.

Comment: Well, there's the simple explanation (which I appreciate) and the nitty gritty details (which I appreciate in a different way).  They're both good answers.

Comment: As mentioned elsewhere, `android:layout_width="0px"` is important.  Also, the weights don't need to be integers.

Comment: This is a bit more difficult to understand than the selected answer, but it gives the complete answer - particularly when some views have weights and some do not. That's a huge use case not covered by the selected answer.

Comment: I want to disagree that this is hard to understand. It is the reverse, he let us know why they called it WEIGHT. Because of it means importance. As in what he says carries alot of weight. I also disagree that the first answer simple and to the point. The answer still left me scratching my mind, and completing ignorant to what the attribute does. This answer is golden. I now have firm footing.

Comment: Adding to this answer, there is LinearLayout.android:weightSum which is handy. You can explicitly tell the compiler the total to use when calculating the remaining space.

Comment: For a better understanding, you can imagine the distribution in percent.
Means you have e.g. 3 buttons, one of them takes half of the screen, the other two fill the second half.
Then you can set the weights like this: `50, 25, 25`

Answer (score 75):

adding to the other answers, the most important thing to get this to work is to set the layout width (or height) to 0px

```
android:layout_width="0px"
```

otherwise you will see garbage

Comment: I think it depends if you want to hide views which don't define their weights or you want to show them with size-to-fit size and leave the remaining free space to the "weighted" views.

Answer (score 45):

If there are multiple views spanning a `LinearLayout`, then `layout_weight` gives them each a proportional size. A view with a bigger `layout_weight` value "weighs" more, so it gets a bigger space.

Here is an image to make things more clear.

[image]

### Theory

The term layout weight is related to the concept of [weighted average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean) in math. It is like in a college class where homework is worth 30%, attendance is worth 10%, the midterm is worth 20%, and the final is worth 40%. Your scores for those parts, when weighted together, give you your total grade.

[image]

It is the same for layout weight. The `Views` in a horizontal `LinearLayout` can each take up a certain percentage of the total width. (Or a percentage of the height for a vertical `LinearLayout`.)

### The Layout

The `LinearLayout` that you use will look something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <!-- list of subviews -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Note that you must use `layout_width="match_parent"` for the `LinearLayout`. If you use `wrap_content`, then it won't work. Also note that `layout_weight` does not work for the views in RelativeLayouts (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16708014/3681880) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14009266/3681880) for SO answers dealing with this issue).

### The Views

Each view in a horizontal `LinearLayout` looks something like this:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Note that you need to use `layout_width="0dp"` together with `layout_weight="1"`. Forgetting this causes many new users problems. (See [this article](http://ugia.io/2012/01/19/android-linearlayout-distribution-explained-weight-and-sizes/) for different results you can get by not setting the width to 0.) If your views are in a *vertical* `LinearLayout` then you would use `layout_height="0dp"`, of course.

In the `Button` example above I set the weight to 1, but you can use any number. It is only the total that matters. You can see in the three rows of buttons in the first image that I posted, the numbers are all different, but since the proportions are the same, the weighted widths don't change in each row. Some people like to use decimal numbers that have a sum of 1 so that in a complex layout it is clear what the weight of each part is.

One final note. If you have lots of nested layouts that use `layout_weight`, it can be bad for performance.

### Extra

Here is the xml layout for the top image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="android:layout_weight="
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="android:layout_weight="
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:text="10" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:text="20" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:text="10" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="android:layout_weight="
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:text=".25" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".50"
            android:text=".50" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:text=".25" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I always wonder why more people don't post images to accompany their XML. It's much easier to understand visuals than code.

Answer (score 30):

**`layout_weight`** tells Android how to distribute your `View`s in a `LinearLayout`. Android then first calculates the total proportion required for all `View`s that have a weight specified and places each `View` according to what fraction of the screen it has specified it needs. In the following example, Android sees that the `TextView`s have a `layout_weight` of `0` (this is the default) and the `EditText`s have a `layout_weight` of `2` each, while the `Button` has a weight of `1`. So Android allocates 'just enough' space to display `tvUsername` and `tvPassword` and then divides the remainder of the screen width into 5 equal parts, two of which are allocated to `etUsername`, two to `etPassword` and the last part to `bLogin`:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" ...>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvUsername" 
    android:text="Username" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" ... />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/etUsername"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2" ... />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tvPassword"
    android:text="Password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/etPassword"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2" ... />

    <Button android:id="@+id/bLogin"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Login"... />

</LinearLayout>
```

It looks like:
[image: landscape orientation]
and
[image: portrait orientation]

Answer (score 16):

Think it that way, will be simpler

If you have 3 buttons and their weights are 1,3,1 accordingly, it will work like table in HTML

Provide 5 portions for that line: 1 portion for button 1, 3 portion for button 2 and 1 portion for button 1

Regard,

Answer (score 10):

one of the best explanations for me was [this one (from the Android tutorial, look for step 7)](http://code.google.com/android/intro/tutorial-ex2.html):

> layout_weight is used in LinearLayouts to assign "importance" to Views within the layout. All Views have a default layout_weight of zero, meaning they take up only as much room on the screen as they need to be displayed. Assigning a value higher than zero will split up the rest of the available space in the parent View, according to the value of each View's layout_weight and its ratio to the overall layout_weight specified in the current layout for this and other View elements.
>
> To give an example: let's say we have a text label and two text edit elements in a horizontal row. The label has no layout_weight specified, so it takes up the minimum space required to render. If the layout_weight of each of the two text edit elements is set to 1, the remaining width in the parent layout will be split equally between them (because we claim they are equally important). If the first one has a layout_weight of 1 and the second has a layout_weight of 2, then one third of the remaining space will be given to the first, and two thirds to the second (because we claim the second one is more important).

Answer (score 7):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#linearlayout

layout_weight defines how much space the control must obtain respectively to other controls.

Answer (score 7):

**For additional**：

For `vertical` orientation, don't forget set `height` to 0dp

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

For `horizontal` orientation, don't forget set `width` to 0dp

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Answer (score 3):

Please look at the weightSum of LinearLayout and the layout_weight of each View. android:weightSum="4" android:layout_weight="2" android:layout_weight="2" Their layout_height are both 0px, but I am not sure it is relevan

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="4">

<fragment android:name="com.example.SettingFragment"
    android:id="@+id/settingFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/dummy_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:text="DUMMY"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please look at the weightSum of LinearLayout and the layout_weight of each View. 

android:weightSum="4"
android:layout_weight="2"
android:layout_weight="2"
Their layout_height are both 0px, but I am not sure it is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Combining both answers from

Flo & rptwsthi and roetzi,

Do remember to change your `layout_width=0dp/px`, else the `layout_weight` behaviour will act reversely with biggest number occupied the smallest space and lowest number occupied the biggest space.

Besides, some weights combination will caused some layout cannot be shown (since it over occupied the space).

Beware of this.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"` will resize the text for you automatically

Answer (score -1):

As the name suggests, Layout weight specifies what amount or percentage of space a particular field or widget should occupy the screen space.
If we specify weight in horizontal orientation, then we must specify `layout_width = 0px`.
Similarly, If we specify weight in vertical orientation, then we must specify `layout_height = 0px`.