# how to separate icons from eachother android

Tags: android, android-layout

i have a navigation bar on the bottom of the screen. I have a set of 3 buttons in this navbar, the buttons have an icon as background button there's no space between eachother. I've been searching in Google how to separate them from eachother but i haven't succeded. The questiion is: how can i separate them from eachother? here's is my xml code:

**Main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#5E767E"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

        <Button 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/back" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        />

        <Button 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/home" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        />

        <Button 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/next" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried putting an empty View in between?

```
<Button 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/back" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        />
<View android:layout_width="2dip" android:layout_height="1dip"/>
        <Button 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/home" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        />
<View android:layout_width="2dip" android:layout_height="1dip"/>
        <Button 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/next" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        />
```

Play with the width and height of it to suit your needs. It usually does the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

Apply margin or padding, for instance:

```
    <Button 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/back" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:margin="10dip"
    />
```

Or:

```
    <Button 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/back" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:marginLeft="10dip"
    android:marginRight="10dip"
    />
```

This could be useful for you: [Difference between a View's Padding and Margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619899/difference-between-a-views-padding-and-margin)

Comment: i tried padding but it didn't work, and margin is not suitable in this case because the buttons don't get centered. Any suggestions?

Comment: And what does margin have to do with being centered?

Comment: To your middle button only add:   android:layout_marginLeft="40dip"
android:layout_marginRight="40dip" - that will make it centre about a vertical axis

Comment: Thanks NickT it worked beautifully but i have a question. If i have a smaller or bigger screen (device), would  this android:layout_marginLeft="40dip" android:layout_marginRight="40dip"

Comment: Thanks NickT it worked beautifully but if i put more icons they wont be centered. I'm looking for a way to center and set a distance between them automatically using padding or something else. When i used padding the icons got like sketched, deformed. This wont happen as long as i don't have a background in the button or if i use android:drawableLeft. Any suggestions? If not, just say it and i will mark this answer as correct. Thanks a lot!