# get spacing between columns android sdk

Tags: android, layout, spacing

I have four columns and four buttons I got them to all line up like I want it to, but they are all scrunched together. is there anyway to make it so that the layouts have spacing? this is what I have:

```
 <TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="4">

    <TableRow>

        <Button 
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:id="@+id/Button01" 
            android:onClick="OnClick" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/Button01">
        </Button>

        <Button 
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:id="@+id/Button02" 
            android:onClick="OnClick" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/Button02">
        </Button>

        <Button 
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:id="@+id/Button03" 
            android:onClick="OnClick" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/Button03" >
        </Button>

                    <Button 
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:id="@+id/Button04" 
            android:onClick="OnClick" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/Button04" >
        </Button>

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured something that works. I added more columns and in-between each column I add a blank transparent image. working pretty well.

Comment: have a look at this question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662038/how-to-separate-icons-from-eachother-android

Comment: I agree adding "blank" columns for spacing seems to work the best!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to experiment with the `android:layout_margin` attribute on each of those Buttons. There's separate padding attributes for top,bottom,left and right.

Comment: That seemed to just make the button bigger didn't actually space anything.

Comment: ah, sorry, you should try android:layout_margin instead. That should do the trick.