# Android's box model

Tags: android, android-layout, css

Rather surprised that I haven't been able to found detailed information about Android's box model. I mean how padding, margins, gravities, etc. they all interact together.

Other than this [note about margin and padding](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#SizePaddingMargins) in the dev site and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619899/difference-between-a-views-padding-and-margin) there's not much information out there.

What I'm looking for:

- What are the defaults for margins, paddings, gravities, etc.
- Can manufacturers alter those defaults. If so, is it a good practice ignoring those defaults so your app looks consistent across different manufacturers?
- How are conflicts resolved, specially between a component and its children.
- Any difference between Android versions?

Is it really that simple that is not worth a deeper explanation in the docs?

Thanks,

Juan

Answer (score 5):

> Rather surprised that I haven't been able to found detailed information about Android's box model.

Note that little in your question has anything to do with `LinearLayout`, the Android equivalent of the "box model" found in XUL or Flex. Perhaps you have a different definition of "box model" than I use.

> What are the defaults for margins, paddings, gravities, etc.

0 pixels for the default margin and padding. Default gravity varies by widget/container.

> Can manufacturers alter those defaults.

Technically, yes, though I am not aware of this being done in practice.

> How are conflicts resolved, specially between a component and its children.

There are no possible conflicts in margin, padding, or gravity.

> Any difference between Android versions?

Not that I am aware of.

> Is it really that simple that is not worth a deeper explanation in the docs?

IMHO, yes.

Comment: With conflicts I mean things like defining a padding for the same element in styles.xml, in line and in a 9.patch asset. Granted, that's not something you want to do on purpose, but it CAN happen and drive you mad, right? Maybe I should've said precedence instead of conflict?

Comment: AFAIK precedence is as follows, in decending priority order. **1)** Any attribute values in the given `AttributeSet` _(these are generally individual attrs specified in the layout file)_ **2)** The `style` resource specified in the AttributeSet _(named "style" in layout file)_ **3)** The default styles specified by defStyleAttr _(attribute in the current theme that points to a style)_ and `defStyleRes` _(a actual style reference specifies in the overloaded constructor)_ ...

Comment: ...and finally **4)** The base values in the current contexts `theme`. These are grabbed from the context used when calling `Context.obtainStyledResults(...)`

Comment: In regards to 9-patches. Explicitly setting a padding on a view with a background 9 patch with a content area that is smaller than the source image (i.e. has a padding explicitly defined by the 9-patch) **will override** the 9-patch padding - usually to ill-effect!

Answer (score 0):

If you compare Android's box model to CSS's box model, I find Android's indeed easier to grasp, and of much lower complexity. You don't have those shenanigans like the padding getting added up to the element's width. IMHO, positioning logic (CSS: float/absolute/relative etc.) is very well and elegantly encapsulated in Android's layout components. While some things are hard to do in Android (like having a toolbar at the view's bottom and filling the rest with a list - but this also involves evil hackery in CSS), it's much more predictable than CSS.

I would suggest that you read up on all layout components, as the box model is straightforward (margin, padding, width, height), and most of positioning and alignment is layout-component-specific (e.g., "gravity" in LinearLayout, "layout_above/below/toLeftOf/toRightOf" in RelativeLayout,...).

BUT: I agree that a complete guide (+ good examples and analogies) on that topic would help novices to come to terms with Android layouts much quicker, since some in-depth info is only available as case-based code snippets (speaking only of the web, books surely do a better job).

As a side-note on the box-model: One "peculiarity" I have stumbled upon is that [9-patch-drawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) which are set as a background to an element affect the element's padding. If the box-padding of the 9-patch is not 0, the element's padding is set accordingly, if not overridden. This really bit me in the butt once.