# Tops of text cutoff in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText in a RelativeLayout where the tops of the text in the EditText are getting cutoff.  I have tried increasing the padding for the EditText, but even at 20dp, the text still gets clipped.

I tried to post an image here, but apparently I don't have enough of a reputation for stackoverflow to allow me to post one. Imagine a lined paper with a dotted line horizontally in the middle like you had in grade school.  The text gets clipped for anything above the dotted line.

Here is my layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/questionTextView"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
              android:textSize="16dp"
              android:text="Audit Question"/>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/answerRadioButton"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_below="@id/questionTextView"
                 android:layout_alignLeft="@id/questionTextView"
                 android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                 android:checked="true"
                 android:textSize="16dp"
                 android:text="audit answer"/>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/commentEditText"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_below="@id/answerRadioButton"
              android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
              android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
              android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
              android:padding="20dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unclear as to why this worked, but when I added a TextView buffer at the bottom below the EditText widget, the text was no longer cutoff.

I added this:

```
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="5dp" />
```

And the text within the EditText now looks as it should.

Answer (score 2):

[Difference between a View's Padding and Margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619899/difference-between-a-views-padding-and-margin)

`Padding` will add space been the content of your `EditText` view and the border constaints of itself, meaning it might be the problem as to why your `EditText` is being clipped-- it's contraining itself. Try to add `android:layout_marginTop` to your `EditText` instead, to create space between it and the `RadioButton`.

Answer (score 0):

I found this when I switched a vertical LinearLayout of 4 sub horizontal Layouts to being equally distributed.  I then found that EditText seems to have non-zero padding and margins at the bottom (at least) which seemed to mess up Android's spacing.  Here is one of my 4 horizontal views that worked.  Annoying.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/type_label"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/division_type"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textCapSentences"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
        android:hint="@string/divison_type_hint"/>

</LinearLayout>
```