# Android Padding not affecting layout

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, padding

OK, Im starting to get the hang of how XML operates with the Android interface, but I've ran into a problem...

I just have a HorizontalScrollView with a RelativeLayout inside to which I will place other views later. The HorizontalScrollView as you can see is sitting above a button, and below another button. I like where its placed, but I dont want it exactly right above and below the buttons. I would like some spacing (padding). Ive tried adding padding but it seems to have no effect...

Heres my attempted XML:

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview_xyzInfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_refresh"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button_mySettings"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/refresh_selector" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </RelativeLayout>

 </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: just add some Bottom and Top margin to your ScrollView

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind! Use margins when seperating two views like so:

```
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
```

Answer Found at:
[Padding not working Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816274/padding-not-working-android)

Comment: If you are going to add the same margins to left, right, top AND bottom you can just say **android:layout_margin="10dp"** :)

Answer (score -2):

Padding and margin works only with LinearLayout. Which layout are you using?

Comment: This is probably more appropriate as a comment rather than an answer to the question.