# Android: Spacing between Imageviews

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

Hi i have 4 images side by side i am trying to increase spacing between imageviews...but itz not working ..tried both setSpacing(int)in java...android:spacing in xml layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/navigationImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:spacing="15dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/streetViewImage"
        android:src="@drawable/streetview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:spacing="15dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/phoneImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:spacing="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

this is my java code

```
 ImageView Image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.navImage);
 Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.navigation);
 Image.setSpacing(5);
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: set left margin inspite of spacing and padding like `android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"`

Comment: @Nishant..hi with android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" i am getting spacing only for first image ...rest are still close to each other

Comment: add `android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"` to all the other `ImageView` also.

Comment: i added ..still no change...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn about the difference between `padding` and `margin`:

[Difference between padding and margin on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619899/difference-between-a-views-padding-and-margin)