# Android - match_parent ignores layout_margin

Tags: android, android-layout

My activity has a `LinearLayout` with a single child view. I want both to fill the screen, minus a 12 dp margin.

Unfortunately, the child view is drawn 12 dp too big and gets cut off.  Apparently `match_parent` ignores the `layout_margin` attribute when calculating the size of the child view.  What is the simplest way to fix this?

**myActivity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <com.myapp.myView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

**myActivity.java**

```
package com.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class myActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myActivity);
    }
}
```

**myView.java**

```
package com.myapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class myView extends View {

    private Paint paint = new Paint();

    public myView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        paint.setColor(0xFFFF0000); //red
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); // for unfilled rectangles
        paint.setStrokeWidth(4);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        int size = canvas.getWidth(); // width = height (see onMeasure())
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, size, size, paint);   
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
        // This gives us a square canvas!
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using `android:padding="12dp"` in your layout instead of `layout_margin`.

Comment: See my comment to Ridcully's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Child views can have a margin around them, parent views (or view groups like layouts) can have a padding between their boundaries and their child views. In other words,  margin is outside a view, padding is inside.

Also, see this excellent explanation: [Difference between a View's Padding and Margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619899/difference-between-a-views-padding-and-margin)

**Example with standard View and padding instead of margin:**

I created a little example with a standard view instead of your custom one, and using padding for the LinearLayout as suggested above and it works perfectly (see screenshot):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#ff0000"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: screenshot from layout editor]

**Solution**

Turns out, the problem was your using `canvas.getWidth()` in your custom view's `onDraw` method. Using the view's `getWidth()` instead, solved the problem. Finally :-)

Comment: Changing layout_margin to padding leaves me with the same problem, except that the outer layout now fills the entire screen and only the inner layout has the 12dp margin.  I'm going to stick with layout_margin.  Do you know what is causing my problem?

Comment: Perhaps it's the implementation of your custom view? Have you tried a normal `View`?

Comment: I'm drawing lines on a canvas in the child view.  If you'd like, I can post a minimal test case.

Comment: It would be interesting if and how you implement the onMeasure() method, because that's where the actual size of the view is calculated.

Comment: Funny you should mention that, since I actually have overridden it!  See my edited post.

Comment: Hm, should probably work, but can you try without the overridden method and just set layout_height to a dedicated height, e.g. 100dp? Just to check if it would work then.

Comment: It's still cut off after those changes.

Comment: Hm, perhaps you can post a minimal test case of your view?

Comment: I've created a test layout with a standard View instead of your custom view and the suggested padding instead of margin, and it works perfectly.

Comment: You're right, although there's no way to tell with your particular example since every part of the image looks the same lol.  I think the problem is the use of `canvas.getWidth()`.  Do you know of an alternate way to get the size of the canvas before drawing on it?

Comment: You can try using the View's getWidth() and getHeight(), which should have the correct values after layout is done.

Comment: Wow, you're right!  I just had to change `canvas.getWidth()` to `this.getWidth()`!  Could you put this answer into your original post so I can accept it?

Comment: I updated my answer. I'm glad we finally found a solution for you. Cheers.