# Getting the margin for two imageviews in android

Tags: android, imageview, margin

I have two imageviews which has to be aligned side by side. So, I used linearlayout with horizontal orientation and having weight same for each imageview width wise. This works fine, but I need the separation between two imageviews to be visible. So, I kept **android:padding** but it doesn't seem to have any affect still. For the better idea on my problem, please refer the picture I pasted below.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    >

  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/imagebgd"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />
  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:padding = "5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/imagebgd"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

**As you can see here, there is no separation visible.**

However, I do have another problem. I kept `nine patch image as background(orange color)` for the imageview to have border for the imageview,
but the border's padding changes from one image to other i.e., border thickness around the imageview changes, but I want it to have stable thickness irrespective of the images. Can someone please help me on these things?

**Note:** I know the hacks like surrounding each imageview again by a linearlayout or Keeping an empty view between imageviews. But I just want to achieve it with preferred things. Because it works for other views when I add padding, why not for these?

Answer (score 2):

replace `android:padding` with `android:layout_margin`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    >

  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/imagebgd"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />
  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_margin = "5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/imagebgd"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

**Padding** is the space inside the border, between the border and the actual view's content.

**Margins** are the spaces outside the border, between the border and the other elements next to this view.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619899/difference-between-a-views-padding-and-margin/4619943#4619943) on learning the difference between padding and margins

Comment: Thanks +1, it worked. Can you please answer my second question regarding the thickness of the background which is 9-patch?

Comment: You have given the 2 `imageviews` with `layout_weight`. So the `imageview` will take equal widths of the screen and it will result in different borders on different sides.

Comment: Then what should I do to have equal thickness for the border even for different images? Just like it has to be like a photo frame in which images can be expanded to get fit in that frame, but the frame should not change. Please suggest.

Comment: I think you have to put two `linearlayouts` with `layout_weight` and put the `imageviews` inside them and give proper width and height.

Answer (score 1):

Give `margin` instead `padding` to your imageview.

use

> android:layout_margin="5dp"

Instead

> android:padding="5dp"

*Simple difference:*

- Padding effect inside of your view.
- Margin effect outside of your view.

Comment: Thanks +1, it worked with below answer, but I can see your answer is also same. Can you please answer my second question regarding the thickness of the background which is 9-patch?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Add `View` you will get space between two image

```
<View  android:layout_width="10dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And also add some background for this `View`