# Even distribution across the whole width

Tags: android, xml, layout

After trying the whole morning I give up and ask you guys (android layouts can be a real pain!):
How can I evenly distribute some text views inside a horizontal linear layout?

This image is how it looks right now (in case you wonder: the text views have a custom style).

[Valid XHTML http://www.vankurt.de/share/layout.png](http://www.vankurt.de/share/layout.png).

And as a bonus question: how could I add a little space between the text views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `android:layout_weight="1"` on each of your text views and a width of `"fill_parent"`

this will evenly distribute the space between the textviews

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

For a little space between them use `android:layout_margin="5dip"` there are also margins you can add to each side individually eg `android:layout_marginRight="5dip"` adds 5dip margin just to the right.

You could also use padding instead, there's a subtle difference between them, see [this question for the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619899/difference-between-a-views-padding-and-margin)

Comment: Dude, you're awesome. Works like a charm. All those layout attributes can really make it difficult sometimes...