# Items no showing up in ScrollView

Tags: android

I am trying to put a TextView and an EditText into the ScrollView but they are not showing up. When I delete the EditText the TextView does a appear. I am wondering what I am doing wrong and what I can do to fix it. Thanks!

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:hint="Enter List Name here"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:paddingTop="50px"/>

    <ScrollView
            android:paddingTop="20px"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="285dp"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
        android:
        android:paddingTop="10px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40px"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="40px"
        android:layout_height="40px"
        android:text="1."
        android:id="@+id/textView2"/>
            <EditText
                    android:layout_width="40px"
                    android:layout_height="40px"
                    android:hint="Enter List Name here"
                    android:id="@+id/listitem1"
                    android:paddingTop="50px"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `android:layout_height="40px"` set in your `LinearLayout` as well as the `EditText` and the `TextView` so once the `TextView` is laid out there is no room for the other.

Try changing your `height` of your `LinearLayout` to `match_parent`. Also, I say `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent` as the latter is deprecated so you should probably get accustomed to using `match_parent` instead. I assume the `android:` in your `LinearLayout` is a copy/paste error but thought I'd point it out

So try something like

```
<LinearLayout
    android: <!-- something should be here...probably an id   -->
    android:paddingTop="10px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="40px"
        android:layout_height="40px"
        android:text="1."
        android:id="@+id/textView2"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="40px"
        android:layout_height="40px"
        android:hint="Enter List Name here"
        android:id="@+id/listitem1"
        android:paddingTop="50px"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <EditText
                android:layout_width="40px"
                android:layout_height="40px"
                android:hint="Enter List Name here"
                android:id="@+id/listitem1"
                android:paddingTop="50px"/>
```

Your padding is bigger than the size of your layout size

[Difference between a View's Padding and Margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619899/difference-between-a-views-padding-and-margin)