# What's the difference between android:height and android:layout_height?

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:paddingTop="48dp"
    android:text="Test"
    />
```

I would expect the TextView to have a measured height of 96dp, regardless of how much space (height-wise) "Test" took up (would expect it to cut off).

Instead, I get the full "Test" + 48dp for the padding.

I can put any valid value for `layout_height` and get the same result.

To get my 96dp height, I need:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="<any valid value>"
    android:height="48dp"
    android:paddingTop="48dp"
    android:text="Test"
    />
```

where again, I can put `layout_height` as any valid value (but it needs to be there as a required attribute).

I've never used the `height` attribute in XML but I couldn't find the difference in the docs, particularly how each one is calculated when the element it's operating on also has values set for padding and/or margin.

Are there any resources available which discuss it, or can someone explain it here?

- [android:layout_height](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_height)
- [android:height](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aheight)
- [LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#MATCH_PARENT)

---

## Edit (summary of questions):

It might be the situation I used it in, which was causing an issue, so my **examples from above can be ignored** (I tried in a fresh project and got different results from the combinations of attributes).

But my original questions still apply (some overlaps):

1. what's the difference between them?
2. when should one be used over the other?
3. does the use of one affect the use of the other?
4. does the use of one have implications over other attributes which can control the measured dimensions of a view, like padding or margin?

---

Edit 2 (an aside):

In case it helps understand my initial situation as compared with the fresh project:

I have an activity which sets `windowActionBarOverlay` as true, so I get my content flowing under the (translucent) ActionBar.

I also use Croutons, which now were appearing under the ActionBar. Ben Weiss suggested I attach the Crouton to a different ViewGroup, but I wasn't sure which ViewGroup to attach it to.

Instead, I supplied a custom view (which is inflated when it is required) as the Crouton (the TextView from the first part of the question) with a top padding equal to that of the ActionBar, so now it displays vertically below the ActionBar as normal (with other issues for another day).

Comment: could someone suggest how I could improve this question such that it doesn't warrant an anonymous downvote?

Comment: here is a similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091531/what-is-use-of-androidheight-attribute-despite-having-androidlayout-height

Comment: Thanks @Prince, I've voted to close based on this... edit: even though yours was after. Clearly mine was `tl;dr` :P

Comment: @ataulm Google will find this question first if “android layout_height vs height” is searched. — Also this question is one month older. — And this question has an exhaustive answer now. — So if anything the other question should be closed.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## Question 1:

#### (what's the difference between them?):

All attributes starting with »layout_« are hints for the [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) the [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) is part of. For this each `android.view.ViewGroup` has a set of [LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html). The widget itself does not use them.

The `android:height` parameter is the *initial* size of the `android.view.View`. But if the View is part `ViewGroup` then the `ViewGroup` will resize the objet according to its layout rules.

BTW: newer APIs have a new `android:minHeight` and `android:maxHeight` attribute to clarify programmers intent.

Note that if you don't set `android:height` the view will calculate the size itself. Which is right thing to do most of the time.

## Question 2

#### (when should one be used over the other?):

`ViewGroup` is abstract — the answer to this question depends which actual child class you are using.

Note that `WRAP_CONTENT` tells the to use `ViewGroup` to use `android:height`. Which means that this is the correct parameter to be used in your example.

## Question 3

#### (does the use of one affect the use of the other?):

Yes — and recursively . [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) will read and write the `android:width` attribute to find out the widest object and resized all other object to it.

## Question 4

#### (does the use of one have implications over other attributes which can control the measured dimensions of a view, like padding or margin?)

No for `android:padding` but yes for `android:layout_margin`. Note that margins are a layout parameter and not every layout manager supports margins.

See [margin vs padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619899/difference-between-a-views-padding-and-margin) for details.

## Final words:

It is easier to consider all width and height attributes to be **hints** only. The final say of the size of an object has the layout manager of the used `ViewGroup`.

Answer (score 0):

From playing about with this a bit, I think that `layout_height` is flexible - a preferred height but will still expand/shrink with the content - and `height` is a definite value.

What's happening in your case is that the TextView is wrapping around the `Test` text but still using the 48dp `paddingTop` attribute.

Comment: Yes. But some `android.view.ViewGroup` might actually set height themselves. All depends on the layout strategy used.

Answer (score 0):

Well, android_layout:height specifies the basic height of the VIEW whereas android:height specifies the height of the object (for example, the button in the xml).

Good luck! :)

Comment: Not quite `android_layout:height` is not part of the view. It tells the parent `android.view.ViewGroup` which size you would like to have.

Answer (score 0):

android:height makes the view be exactly this many pixels tall while android:layout_height specifies the basic height of the view.

Comment: Actually: More the other way around.