# What is use of Android:height attribute despite having Android:layout_height

Tags: android, android-layout

What is use of **Android:height** attribute when we already have **Android:layout_height** attribute??
I have tried using it in TextView and EditText ,, have made No usefull difference

Comment: Well, usually layout_* means that this will be applied on itself from the parent and direct attributes affects the childs in the node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aheight)

> Makes the TextView be exactly this many pixels tall.

I'm guessing its something old and is only if you want to dictate, as it says, a specific number of pixels. I wouldn't suggest using it but stick with `android:layout_height`

Comment: Yes I read that Document. Then I tried using it. The Code crashed in the absence of [layout_height] (API 11) , and if we use both [layout_height] and [height] together it doesn't care what [height] says

Comment: To be honest, I have never used it and I doubt anyone has for a long time. As Commonsware said, it was probably needed in the early days but now you must use `android:layout_height` which can do the same thing but more

Comment: @codeMagic you can always set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and then set your desired size in `android:height="wrap_content`

Comment: @Martin I'm not sure what difference that is going to make. It seems redundant since the docs say "You could get the same effect by specifying this number in the layout parameters."

Comment: @codeMagic dam there is a typo. Of course you can't set `android:height="wrap_content"` — And the difference is: you have to set the layout_height but **don't** you have to set the height. Then the object calculates it's hight automaticly. Which is the better idea in most cases anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It all depend on the [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) used but generally if your use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` then `android:height` becomes the actual size.

For details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20728106/341091

Note that if you don't set `android:height` the view will calculate the size itself. Which is right thing to do most of the time.