# This item's height is 45dp. Consider making the height of this touch target 48dp or larger. Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I always set height to 50dp，but still occur this warning[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liYEG.png)

Comment: Set `layout_height` instead of just `height`. If you want to know the difference, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391055/whats-the-difference-between-androidheight-and-androidlayout-height)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `view` is a part of `ViewGroup`, then the `height` will be set according to the `layout` rules. Since you are already bounding `height` to `50dp`, it may cause an error in the runtime.

So the solution is to use `layout_height`.

### WHY?

When using `layout_height`, it becomes a part of `android.view.ViewGroup`. It sets a rule. If needed it can resize the `height`. So its always better to user `layout_height`.

Moreover, one can use `android:maxHeight` or `android:minHeight` to set bounds to the attribute.