# How to add space between two textviews

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android development and I was just wondering how can I add space between two TextViews? Any help would be appreciated.

The code I have written so far

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_group_coworkers"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Coworkers" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@id/lbl_group_"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Family"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Replace parent LinearLayout to RelativeLayout and add android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" in your second textView

Comment: yes it is the easy way as suggested by tj's also.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use android:layout_marginTop="value" 
like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_group_coworkers"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Coworkers" />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@id/lbl_group_"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Family"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 6):

you can have margin between two textview.
add top margin to the second textview

like this

```
 <TextView 
    android:id="@id/lbl_group_"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Family"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just replace `<LinearLayout>  </LinearLayout>`
with `<RelativeLayout>  </RelativeLayout>`
then go in graphical layout and adjust space as you like.

Comment: A solution should be given that is not specific to a layout type.

Answer (score 1):

add margin left right top bottom

```
 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

add `android:layout_marginRight="..."` to the first textView

Answer (score 1):

try adding margin

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbl_group_coworkers"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Coworkers" 
    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

<TextView 

    android:id="@+id/lbl_group"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Family"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`android:layout_margin="5dp"`

or

```
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
```

But before you ask a lot more such questions, I'd suggest to read through the android dev guides ( http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html )

Good Luck and have fun developing...

Answer (score 1):

You can use either padding or margin depending on what you need, here is a link of a guy who gives a good explanation between the two that will help you decide on which one you'd like to use: [android margin vs padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619899/difference-between-a-views-padding-and-margin)

Answer (score 1):

set margin property in TextView...

```
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
```

and if all side set space then...

```
android:layout_margin="20dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GridLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="A"
            android:layout_gravity="left" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="B"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/custom_border"
  >
  <TextView
      android:text="@string/textView_reference_number"
      style="@style/CustomTextView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/textView_refernce_number_label"
      />
   <TextView
      android:text="Reference Number Value"
      style="@style/CustomTextView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/textView_refernce_number"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>   
 </LinearLayout>
```

android:layout_marginTop XML attribute is used to specify extra space on the top side of this view. Thus android:layout_marginTop="10dp" on 2nd textView is specifying 10 dp of space between it and above view. @UDI Please refer below link for more details over the same https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html

Comment: Can you explain what are doing in your answer. Simply pasting code won't help any one to understand the concept.

Comment: android:layout_marginTop  XML attribute is used to specify extra space on the top side of this view.  Thus android:layout_marginTop="10dp"  on 2nd textView is specifying 10 dp of space between it and above view.
@UDI
Please refer below link for more details over the same.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html

Comment: Please check it. Hope it helps. Please comment if you require any other help or have any other confusion. @UDID

Comment: Please add this in to answer this will help for future use.