# Edittext input type alignment extra space

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, alignment, android-edittext

I want to give extra space to input texts in my edit text. 
here is what I have now :

[image]

but I want to achieve this :

[image]

which property of edittext will do this (in xml) ? 
or I have to do this in another way ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android:paddingLeft` is the property you need. You can use it as `android:paddingLeft="8dp"`

Checkout this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4619943/1739882

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribute:

```
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
```

padding usually used to give an alignment to the text inside the `EditText` or even `Buttons`

please inform me if this is what you are looking for