# Android: Top and bottom padding of text in listview item

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, android-adapter

I am developing an application in which i am using a custom list view. The XML code is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/loginbg" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="15sp"
        android:background="@android:color/white" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:divider="#000000"
            android:dividerHeight=".5sp" >
        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my custom adapter XML is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingTop="75sp"
        android:paddingBottom="75sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But my out put is not like what i needed. I needed vertical padding of text which i given in adapter textview in XML.

My out put is:

[image: output]

I need space from top and bottem of text in text view which is in adapter of list view.

I tried from .java file also as :

```
textView.setPadding(0, 75, 0, 75);
```

but of no use.

I need output like :

[image]

Please guide me what should i do now.

Comment: For padding use `dp` units instead of `sp` (which should be only used for font sizes)

Comment: Ok but what should i do. I used dp now.

Comment: @ManojFegde used dp and you aren't getting the desired result?

Comment: No i am not getting the result.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need top and bottom then, check this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewn_company_clsa"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="75dp"
        android:text="asdf"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

For the custom layout, inside your `TextView`, use `marginTop` and `marginBottom` (or `layout_margin`)which will give you **space outside the `TextView`'s container**.

**Padding** provides the **space within your container**. For your `ListView` `item`, you **need the space outside** each `row/item` also.

Check:
[Android beginner difference between padding and margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959050/android-beginner-difference-between-padding-and-margin)
[Difference between a View's Padding and Margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619899/difference-between-a-views-padding-and-margin)

```
android:paddingTop="75sp"
android:paddingBottom="75sp"
```

And

```
android:layout_margin="15sp"  
android:dividerHeight=".5sp"
```

Unit needs to be in "dp"..:

```
android:paddingTop="75dp"
android:paddingBottom="75dp"
```

And

```
android:layout_margin="15dp"  
android:dividerHeight=".5dp"
```

For your ref:
[What is the difference between "px", "dp", "dip" and "sp" on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android)
http://www.prandroid.com/2013/03/differences-between-px-dip-dp-and-sp.html

Comment: I done with the changes. But my out put is same. No effect of changes. Please guide me.

Comment: Please have a look on my edit to post. I pasted output what i need.

Comment: In other words, margin and padding are the same: they make space between your thing and the others, but padding fills the space with your view and margin leaves the space empty.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textviewn_company_clsa"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please have a look on my post. I added what i need as a out put.