# Android Layout optimization for ListView of ArrayAdapter: is FrameLayout really useless?

Tags: android, android-layout, optimization, warnings

I have created a color catalogue for my app and have decided to use an Array adapter to inflate this catalogue. My color layout is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fav_swatch"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fav_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fav_swatch"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/fav_swatch"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingStart="30dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fav_coord"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fav_swatch"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/fav_swatch"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fav_name"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingStart="30dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_clear"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_modify"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_delete"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_delete"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_edit"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

My activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fav_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/fav_lv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </ListView>

</FrameLayout>
```

So this code leads to the desired layout as this:

[image: Correct layout]

The problem is that Android warns me

> This `RelativeLayout` or its parent `FrameLayout` is useless

It is not really useless because if I keep only the `RelativeLayout` as parent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fav_swatch"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fav_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fav_swatch"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/fav_swatch"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingStart="30dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fav_coord"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fav_swatch"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/fav_swatch"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fav_name"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingStart="30dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_clear"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_modify"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_delete"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_delete"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_edit"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

the margins are simply ignored and I get this sort of ugly layout:

[image: Undesired layout]

My question is: is there any way to get the right layout without having to put a 'useless' `FrameLayout` to get a cleaner and more optimized code?

EDIT: the interesting java code:

```
// Construct the data source
        ArrayList<Colour> arrayOfColours = new ArrayList<>();

        final ColourAdapter adapter = new ColourAdapter(this, arrayOfColours);

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.fav_lv);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        final Colour[] colour = new Colour[ca.getMaxNumberOfFavColours()];
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfColours; i++) {
            colour[i] = new Colour(colourPixel[i], colourName[i]);
            adapter.add(colour[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scenario `FrameLayout`is containing one child element as `RelativeLayout`. Your all further elements are contained inside `RelativeLayout`. May be this is reason Android Studio is giving you a warning.

> This RelativeLayout or its parent FrameLayout is useless.

I don't understand your point of having `RelativeLayout` inside `FrameLayout`. Instead i would also recommend to use either one of them.

Moreover, you can get the same result just by doing this in your second scenario...

1. removing margin from `RelativeLayout`.
2. instead of margin, add `android:padding="20dp"` in `RelativLayout`.

Let me know if you have any queries related to this.

I would recommend you to [see the diff. in margin and padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959050/android-beginner-difference-between-padding-and-margin) and avoid giving margin to outer most container of your layout.

PS: Developers don't give much attention to warnings until they became errors. :p

Comment: The padding was the key. I guess I still need a better insight of layout attributes. Thanks!

Comment: These layout stuffs, really sometime create big confusion.