# Make LinearLayout adjust it's height to a TextView with "wrap_content" height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview

I have a `LinearLayout` containing an `ImageView` with fixed height, and a `TextView` with `wrap_content` height. I want the `LinearLayout` to grow to fit the entire `TextView` if the text doesn't fit on one line.

My code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/question_mark"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="Some long text that doesnt fit on one line"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The `LinearLayout` in the example above doesn't resize, so I only see `"Some long text"` and then the rest of the `TextView` is hidden.

Any way to get the `LinearLayout` to resize according to the `TextView`?

I know I can use `RelativeLayout` and other types of layouts to achieve this, but I'm asking about a solution using `LinearLayout`.

Comment: make width `match_parent` your main layout.

Comment: post your full xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this :**

[image]

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Some long text that doesnt fit on one line"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I changed the `layout_margin` on the `ImageView` to `padding` instead, so I can have the same `100dp` on the `LinearLayout` and `ImageView` and still contain the `ImageView` inside the `LinearLayout` (it will be 110dp if using margin).

Comment: @BadCash I am not getting. means any issue still remains or it is fully solved??

Comment: It's fully solved, thanks. Just mentioning for others who might find this answer that they need to adjust the width to account for margins, or use padding instead.

Comment: @BadCash I think margin and padding are same in this case. instead if you want 100 dp image you can remove margin padding. padding provides space inside imageview then imageview will also 95 dp.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/21959146/8089770