# Difference between Padding and Margin in React native

Tags: android, ios, node.js, reactjs, react-native

someone, please give more information, in a simpler term what both Margin and Padding means in React native?

I've tried searching online but couldn't find a better definition

Comment: have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619899/difference-between-a-views-padding-and-margin and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959050/android-beginner-difference-between-padding-and-margin

Comment: Solves it, thank you!