# Android: How to justify text in a TextView?

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, text-alignment

This is what i want.
[image: first pic]

And this is what i have.
[image: second pic]

In the above pictures we can see that the lines the paragraph is starting from the most start of the page (aligned start). and in the first picture the lines of paragraph also end of the page (aligned end).
so this is i want with my `TextView`, showing in the second picture but i don't know what to do :(

Comment: This might help you...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text

Comment: margin, padding is not working for this so with the help of @PraveenSP 's comment i found a library to justify the text with github library.

Answer (score 1):

There are two key elements to solve the problem you are currently facing: `margin` and `padding`.

Here's a basic difference between them:

**Padding** separates a view's contents from the boundaries of that view.
**Margin** separates a view from the immediate parent.

Here's a potential solution:

The image above has a significant margin (left and right) and a little padding. Therefore, you need to adjust the following attributes:
`padding_start`
`padding_end`
`margin_start`
`margin_end`

Also, remember to set the `gravity` of the TextView to center.

To learn more about the difference between margin and padding, [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959050/android-beginner-difference-between-padding-and-margin).

Answer (score 1):

Use this sample:

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:justificationMode="inter_word" />
```

This is the command: android:justificationMode="inter_word"

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways in **Kotlin** until this time:

This feature is introduced in Android version >= 8.0.

1- XML

```
<TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:justificationMode="inter_word"
       />
```

2- Programmatically in an Activity:

Android O offers full justification

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
 TextView.setJustificationMode(LineBreaker.JUSTIFICATION_MODE_INTER_WORD);}
```

However, Android Studio mentions that you can use it for **Android Q** , but is still works in **Android O**