# Padding inside EditText

Tags: android, image, text, android-edittext, padding

I'm trying to create a `EditText` with two images inside. I want to give it padding to right and left inside of the EditText. But I when write in EditText, the text reaches all the way to the right and left.

Which can be the error?

```
<LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/buscar_linear"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:visibility="gone" >

                        <FrameLayout
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/buscar_monumento"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:ems="15"
                                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:hint="Buscar..."
                                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                                android:inputType="text"
                                android:padding="40dp"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:textColor="@color/negro"
                                android:textStyle="bold" >
                            </EditText>

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/buscar_lupa"
                                android:layout_width="22dp"
                                android:layout_height="22dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/buscar_lupa" />

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/buscar_salir"
                                android:layout_width="25dp"
                                android:layout_height="25dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/buscar_salir" />
                        </FrameLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try like this

```
  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/buscar_monumento"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:ems="15"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:hint="Buscar..."
      android:imeOptions="actionDone"
      android:inputType="text"
      android:paddingLeft="20dp"
      android:paddingRight="20dp"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:textColor="@color/negro"
      android:textStyle="bold" >
  </EditText>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion is to try and use `layoutMargin` instead of `padding`.

Margin controls the distance BETWEEN views, where-as padding controls the distance of a view from the edge of its own parent.

Bottom line, margin and padding are different, and you may have more success using each in different situations.

Here is a good SO explaining this concept: [Difference between a View's Padding and Margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619899/difference-between-a-views-padding-and-margin)

Comment: There is no code, this is a basic concept important to understand in UI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619899/difference-between-a-views-padding-and-margin

Answer (score 0):

You can use horizontal linearlayout instead of frame layout..

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:orientation = "horizontal">
   <EditText
      android:id="@+id/buscar_monumento"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:ems="15"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:hint="Buscar..."
      android:imeOptions="actionDone"
      android:inputType="text"
      android:padding="40dp"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:textColor="@color/negro"
      android:textStyle="bold" >
   </EditText>

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/buscar_lupa"
     android:layout_width="22dp"
      android:layout_height="22dp"
       android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
      android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
     android:background="@drawable/buscar_lupa" />

     <Button
       android:id="@+id/buscar_salir"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
       android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
         android:background="@drawable/buscar_salir" />
     </LinearLayout>
```