# Absolute Positioning in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to use absolute positioning in such a way that each object in the layout is in about the same position on each device. Is there maybe a library or a formula or something else I can use to achieve this?

Comment: That's simply not possible. Devices have different screen-sizes, resolutions, etc. That is exactly why Android has a flexible layout framework.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly are aware that it's not a very good idea (because you'll have difficulties to adapt to different screen sizes/orientation), however, you may achieve this with FrameLayout and paddings

```
<FrameLayout ...>
    <View
       android:layout_paddingLeft="20dip"
       android:layout_paddingTop="10dip"
       ... />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: The thing is I don't want to use the XML layout because the positions of my objects are dynamic

Comment: Well, in that case, you should : 1- Tell it in you SO question. 2- Change the layout parameters programmatically (use ```FrameLayout.LayoutParams```)

Comment: This is definitely not ideal, but why was `padding` mentioned insteag of `margin`?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Depending on which you choose, you can pick one or the other. There is a very useful visual representation of both solutions there :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619899/difference-between-a-views-padding-and-margin

Answer (score -1):

Use `<AbsoluteLayout ></AbsoluteLayout>`

hope it will work..

Comment: `AbsoluteLayout` has been **deprecated since API Level 3**. Remember Cupcake? Exactly!