# How to removing space between home (and up) button and title on android action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In my app, there is extra space **i dont want between icons and action bar title**.
The menu button is the default one when one creates navigation activity. and the back arrow i brought by including

```
 <activity
            android:name=".ShipmentList"
            android:label="Shimpment"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainNavigationActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.mobile.MainNavigationActivity" />
        </activity>
```

in the AndroidManifest.

[image]

[image]

Comment: please code put here

Comment: Please also include the activity xml code with the `app:title`

Comment: I had a similar problem, maybe the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34610106/5015207) there can help you:

Comment: This happens after I updated to buildToolsVersion '24.0.2' if you don't mind to downgrade stepback to 23 and it will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use these lines in your toolbar.

```
app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
```

**Like this:**

```xml
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/color18"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp" />
```

Comment: Back button or Home Icon are not visible at same time.

Answer (score -2):

On each version upgrade I found some issues with UI changes.
This is an issue with android version 24.
It happened when I installed it and upgraded my build to it.
Maybe this is the new default design by android..
you can build a toolbar instead of the builtin actionBar, then you will be able to padd it as you wish.
Or, if you don't mind - you can downgrade to 23.0.3 and appcompat 23.3.0

*By the way- if you will downgrade to 23.0.0 - 23.2.0 you will have an issue with colorState = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(ChatActivity.this,R.color.mycolor); 
colorstate change on button will have no effect.

any way - this is build.gradle that has a normal padding between home and title in actionBar:

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxx"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.7"
}


buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/felixb/mvn-repo/master/'
    }
    mavenCentral()
}
productFlavors {
}
}
 dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'   
}
```