# Converted Website to android app

Tags: java, android

I have converted my website into an app using Android Studio. However, every time the application open the website is not fit automatically to the screen. What I'm doing wrong? Do this have to deal with the padding? "16dp"

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Comment: Yes, if you have specified that in the root viewgroup. Padding denotes the amount of space used as margin WITHIN the view/viewgroup. For more info : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619899/difference-between-a-views-padding-and-margin

Comment: Do you have a coding layout for that?

Comment: Can you show me what you have done. So that i can better understand what you want.

Comment: ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    tools:context="life.redemptionchurch.nowapp.MainActivity">
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView">
    </WebView>
</RelativeLayout>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the padding you set on your Relativelayout. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this is what you want.