# CardView-TextView marginRight

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am learning android. I am trying to set marginRight in my textview, but its cutting my text and showing empty space in layout. My XML is like below.

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">



<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/quoteCard"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cardBackground"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/authorImage"
            android:layout_width="128dp"
            android:layout_height="128dp"
            app:civ_border_width="2dp"
            app:civ_border_color="#99333333"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/textDetailQuote"
            android:text="The price of success is hard work, dedication to the job at hand, and the determination that whether we win or lose, we have applied the best of ourselves to the task at hand.Read more at: "
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/textAuthorSign"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="- ABJ Abdul Kalam"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This is the image of my issue.... Please check and let me know.

[image]

Please check and let me know what I have wrong in this .

Thanks

Comment: Try to change `android:layout_width="match_parent"` to `wrap_content` in your TextView.

Comment: @Vucko Thanks for suggestion but its still showing same :(

Comment: I found this helpful to understand the concepts of padding and margin, I think you are confusing them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619899/difference-between-a-views-padding-and-margin

Comment: padding also not working :(

Comment: Adding this may resolve the problem `android:singleLine="true"`  `android:includeFontPadding="false"`

Comment: sorry, it have also not solved :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of maringLeft and marginRight use paddingLeft and paddingRight in your textView

```
  <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/textDetailQuote"
        android:text="The price of success is hard work, dedication to the job at hand, and the determination that whether we win or lose, we have applied the best of ourselves to the task at hand.Read more at: "
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Still Same issue :(