# Remove button margin android

Tags: android

I've set a 0 dp margin to the button but it has no effect the little margin on top,bottom,lef and right is still there,How can I remove it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.myapp.mainpackage.MapActivity">



    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="550dp"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot]

There is a space on the button margins that I can't remove,I want the button fill all the space

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean the padding? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619899/difference-between-a-views-padding-and-margin

Comment: The padding of the button container is 0dp

Comment: What do you mean? You have `android:layout_margin="0dp"`, not padding, there

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of what you are trying to do? Perhaps you want a [Borderless Button](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#Borderless)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  The default button comes with margins. Set a button property like this:

```
android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
```

Do the same for the left, right, and bottom margins. Or define a new drawable with these parameters:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:padding="10dp"
    >
    <solid android:color="@color/colorButtonGray"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="2dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="2dp"
        android:topRightRadius="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

The custom shape will not have any built in margins.