# Removing space between design widgets

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am currently learning some design on `XML`. I have a scroll view and I have Several widgets. However, I want to remove space between my Log In and my password, how can I combine them together yet be able to input email and password?

What I want :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58GaV.png)

what I currently have

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rhj9v.png)

Thanks for the help.

So below is my simple code. How can I remove space and have them come together?

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<!--  Password Label -->
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove extra top spacing  by setting `app:hintEnabled="false"` to TextInputLayout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:hintEnabled="false"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">

.....
```

It is space left for *hint*

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the top/bottom margins of the EditText widgets. Like so:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"

    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<!--  Password Label -->
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"

        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" 
/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I would also experiment with the `android:padding` attribute.

More info: [Difference between a View's Padding and Margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619899/difference-between-a-views-padding-and-margin/4619934)

Answer (score 0):

You can put login view and password view into **linear layout**, and **margin_top** and **margin_bottom** = 0

Answer (score 0):

It's not about space between views, it's about view style. So search for style you need your `EditText` appears

Something like this [tutorial](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2013/08/26/android-edittext-control-using-old-rectangle-style/)