# How to arrange buttons without space from each other?

Tags: android

I have buttons, but is there space between them? Any ideas how to clean up the space? Thanks !

[image]

Comment: Please post what have you tried so far

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Share your XML code !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add style for button in XML

```
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
```

and

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```

it requires API level 21 or more..

An example would be

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/btn_send"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Send"
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
android:stateListAnimator="@null" />
```

Comment: Thanks! Not an obvious option. And do not immediately understand how to configure. With your help, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set margin and padding to 0.
But we really need to see your code to help you.

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/mybutton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="0dp"
android:padding="0dp" />
```

[Here is a great explantation what margin and padding do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25520320/3246824)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this option only works with TextView.