# Two Relative Layouts on the one screen

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to have 2 Relative Layouts on my screen. One below another. I made this code but it doesn't work. In this case i can see only upper Relative Layout insted of both and this layout take whole space although i set wrap_content.

EDIT!: I put below the second code which fails too.

EDIT 2!: I found problem... That's a bit... sad. Problem lie in my theme. I set background to png file which was too big and when i applied default theme via manifest then this happend. When i removed it all is good.

This version fails too.

New code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/some_id" 
        android:layout_above="@+id/some_id2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/main_button_localize" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="@string/main_localize" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@id/some_id2" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  >

        <ToggleButton 
            android:id="@+id/main_help" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Old code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/maps_manager_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <!-- Top -->
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/maps_manager_top_left" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty" />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/maps_manager_top_middle" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/maps_manager_top_left"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty" />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/maps_manager_top_right" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/maps_manager_top_middle"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty" />

        <!-- Middle -->
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/maps_manager_middle_left" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/maps_manager_top_left"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty" />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/maps_manager_middle_middle" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/maps_manager_middle_left"
            android:layout_below="@id/maps_manager_top_middle"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty" />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/maps_manager_middle_right" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/maps_manager_middle_middle"
            android:layout_below="@id/maps_manager_top_right"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty" />

        <!-- Bottom -->
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/maps_manager_bottom_left" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/maps_manager_middle_left"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty" />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/maps_manager_bottom_middle" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/maps_manager_bottom_left"
            android:layout_below="@id/maps_manager_middle_middle"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty" />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/maps_manager_bottom_right" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/maps_manager_bottom_middle"
            android:layout_below="@id/maps_manager_middle_right"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
           android:id="@+id/maps_manager_controls"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/maps_manager_menu" >

            <ToggleButton 
                android:id="@+id/maps_manager_help" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I checked it on eclipse , I am able to see both the relative layouts one below the other.

Comment: change match_parent to wrap_content

Comment: android:layout_alignBottom="true" by  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  in second relative layout

Comment: @RajeevNB
My code works in your eclipse? Unchanged? I changed alignBottom to aliginParentBottom, nothing has happend.

Comment: @SardorDushamov
Change match to wrap but where?
I wonder why wrap_content doesn't work...

Comment: @MichalW change all match_parent

Comment: check this stuff [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432763/whats-the-difference-between-fill-parent-and-wrap-content)! Understand the differnce,made changes in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Better you take LinearLayout with vertical orientation as Parent for two child RelativeLayouts. If you can put 80:20 height weights for the RelativeLayouts then it would fit to the entire screen.

Comment: I'll think about this if no other answer will come.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ScrollView 
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
             <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/maps_manager_menu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

            <!-- Top -->
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/maps_manager_top_left" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:contentDescription="@string/empty" />

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/maps_manager_top_middle" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/maps_manager_top_left"
                android:contentDescription="@string/empty" />

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/maps_manager_top_right" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/maps_manager_top_middle"
                android:contentDescription="@string/empty" />

            <!-- Middle -->
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/maps_manager_middle_left" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/maps_manager_top_left"
                android:contentDescription="@string/empty" />

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/maps_manager_middle_middle" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/maps_manager_middle_left"
                android:layout_below="@id/maps_manager_top_middle"
                android:contentDescription="@string/empty" />

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/maps_manager_middle_right" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/maps_manager_middle_middle"
                android:layout_below="@id/maps_manager_top_right"
                android:contentDescription="@string/empty" />

            <!-- Bottom -->
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/maps_manager_bottom_left" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/maps_manager_middle_left"
                android:contentDescription="@string/empty" />

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/maps_manager_bottom_middle" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/maps_manager_bottom_left"
                android:layout_below="@id/maps_manager_middle_middle"
                android:contentDescription="@string/empty" />

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/maps_manager_bottom_right" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/maps_manager_bottom_middle"
                android:layout_below="@id/maps_manager_middle_right"
                android:contentDescription="@string/empty" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
               android:id="@+id/maps_manager_controls"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/maps_manager_menu" >

                <ToggleButton 
                    android:id="@+id/maps_manager_help" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: ScrollView can hava only one child : /

Comment: you can use scrollview as root tag and set its layout parameter to wrap content

Answer (score 1):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/maps_manager_menu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

            <!-- Top -->
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/maps_manager_top_left" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world" />

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/maps_manager_top_middle" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/maps_manager_top_left"
                android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world" />

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/maps_manager_top_right" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/maps_manager_top_middle"
                android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world" />

            <!-- Middle -->
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/maps_manager_middle_left" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/maps_manager_top_left"
                android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world" />

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/maps_manager_middle_middle" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/maps_manager_middle_left"
                android:layout_below="@id/maps_manager_top_middle"
                android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world" />

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/maps_manager_middle_right" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/maps_manager_middle_middle"
                android:layout_below="@id/maps_manager_top_right"
                android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world" />

            <!-- Bottom -->
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/maps_manager_bottom_left" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/maps_manager_middle_left"
                android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world" />

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/maps_manager_bottom_middle" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/maps_manager_bottom_left"
                android:layout_below="@id/maps_manager_middle_middle"
                android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world" />

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/maps_manager_bottom_right" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/maps_manager_bottom_middle"
                android:layout_below="@id/maps_manager_middle_right"
                android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
               android:id="@+id/maps_manager_controls"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/maps_manager_menu" >

                <ToggleButton 
                    android:id="@+id/maps_manager_help" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Almost, now i see both relatives but each of them has size equal to screen size. That's bad.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps:

1. Add ID to topmost relative layout say: android:id="@+id/rtvlt_first"
2. In second RelativeLayout  remove alignparenttop property.
3. Add android:tobottomof="@id/rtvlt_first"...
   Try this....

   Good Luck!

Comment: tobottomof is unrecognizable : /