# error: Error: Integer types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value '10')

Tags: android, types, integer

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="63dp"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

Everytime I enter the text without string it gives me a yellow I sign. So I made a string. Now I get the above message at layout_height. I am new to android development.

Answer (score 11):

Use either dp or sp for specify with integer values

```
 android:layout_height="10dp"
```

or

```
 android:layout_height="35sp"
```

Answer (score 5):

u should specify heght in dp.

height and weight properties are unit based. u cant simply add integer.

```
android:layout_height="10dp"
```

check these lnks too

[What is the difference between "px", "dp", "dip" and "sp" on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension

[What's the difference between fill_parent and wrap_content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432763/whats-the-difference-between-fill-parent-and-wrap-content)