# How can I center a TextView on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a simple layout that only has one `EditText` and one `TextView`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="vertical">

             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

             <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/txtName"/>
        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And I want to center the `TextView` to the center of the screen of my mobile phone.

I saw that I can replace my `LinearLayout` to a `RelativeLayout` as global layout and set the property `android:gravity="center"` to center it, but I **ONLY** want to center the `TextView` and not the `EditText`, which it's also centered with this function.

Is it possible to center just the `TextView` without center the `EditText`?

**Note:** Of course, I don't want to center it manually with margins.

**EDIT:** I want that the TextView will be center on the screen and the EditText will be in the nextLine (on the left of the screen). Something like this:

```
[                WIDHT OF THE SCREEN                ]
                 [TEXTVIEW-CENTER]
[EDITTEXT-LEFT]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have an image to depict exactly what you want? Where do you want the edittext to be? Above or below the textview or on the side?

Comment: Can someone explain me why the downvote?

Comment: @Fareya Oh, sorry now I edit my question but I don't know how to add an image. Thanks for correct me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your inside LinearLayout to something like this.`

```
    <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical">
```

`
It will acquire all the screen space then EditText would be displayed.

If you use wrap_content in your inner Linear_layout then thw width of the inner Linear_layour would be wrapped according to its textView i.e it will act as a parent to textview but child for its outside layout. refer to the image.

[image]

but if you chnage its attribute to fill_parent it will fill the width according to its parent.
I hope you can understand it now.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was exactly what I needed! But... can you please explain me what it's the difference between put here `wrap_content` and `fill_parent`? And why with `wrap_content` it is displayed on the left of the screen? Thanks again!

Comment: I am glad to hear that it helped you. Please accept this as an answer if I answered your question correctly.

Comment: fill=parent means to fill the parent i.e a layout with fill=parent attribute will try to fill its parent but in case of warp_content it will try to warp it contents i.e in your case your textview size was small it was trying to warp its layout.

Comment: Can you please put a bit elaborate explanation in your answer instead of a comment? I don't really understand what you mean in that comment and I won't have any problem to mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: I edited my answer.if you still don't understand please refer to this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432763/whats-the-difference-between-fill-parent-and-wrap-content

Comment: Good answer. But just an observation. Use `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent` as the last one is deprecated.

Comment: Now I understand it better but I have one more question: then `wrap_content` it's always displayed on the left of the screen? I mean, the `TextView` could be so big as the content is (wrapping it), but couldn't be center? And just a note: the `TextView` it's also inside the inner `LinearLayout`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Test"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/txtName"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

> android:orientation="horizontal"

to

> android:orientation="vertical"

Add

> android:layout_gravity="center"

in

> TextView

Comment: The `TextView` it's still on the left of the screen.

Comment: Did you change the orientation to vertical?

Comment: Yes I changed it and it also doesn't work. I noticed now that I didn't put on my question that I have a `LinearLayout` wrapping both `EditText` and `TextView` (I though I put it before) so I'm going to edit my question.

Comment: your parent `LinearLayout` has a width of `wrap_content`, so it will center in as small a width as required to fit the children.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I edited my question now because I forgot to put on my question that it was wrapped in another `LinearLayout` but according to this I think it should works but it's only on the left of the screen all the time.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Sample Text"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/txtName"/>
</LinearLayout>
```