# Got troubles with designing a layout

Tags: android, button, layout

I'm trying to build an alarm clock app, however I get trouble on designing the layout.

I want to add a `button` below the `toggle button`, but the button is not showing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Alarm"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <View android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_width="340sp" android:layout_height="2dp" android:background="#c0c0c0" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Repeat"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ToggleButton

            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_width="55sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textOn="@string/Sun"
            android:textOff="@string/Sun"
            android:checked="false"
            android:id="@+id/toggleSun" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
            android:layout_width="57sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/toggleSun"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/toggleSun"
            android:textOn="@string/Mon"
            android:textOff="@string/Mon"
            android:id="@+id/toggleMon"
            android:checked="false" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
            android:layout_width="55sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textOn="@string/Tue"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/toggleMon"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/toggleMon"
            android:textOff="@string/Tue"
            android:id="@+id/toggleTue"
            android:checked="false" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
            android:layout_width="55sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textOn="@string/Wed"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/toggleTue"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/toggleTue"
            android:textOff="@string/Wed"
            android:id="@+id/toggleWed"
            android:checked="false" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
            android:layout_width="55sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textOn="@string/Thu"
            android:textOff="@string/Thu"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/toggleWed"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/toggleWed"
            android:id="@+id/toggleThurs"
            android:checked="false" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
            android:layout_width="55sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textOn="@string/Fri"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/toggleThurs"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/toggleThurs"
            android:textOff="@string/Fri"
            android:id="@+id/toggleFri"
            android:checked="false" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
            android:layout_width="55sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/toggleFri"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/toggleFri"
            android:textOn="@string/Sat"
            android:textOff="@string/Sat"
            android:id="@+id/toggleSat"
            android:checked="false" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.20">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Alarm"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />

        <TimePicker
            android:id="@+id/timePicker"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <View android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_width="340sp" android:layout_height="2dp" android:background="#c0c0c0" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Repeat"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.60">

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ToggleButton

                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_width="55sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textOn="@string/Sun"
                android:textOff="@string/Sun"
                android:checked="false"
                android:id="@+id/toggleSun" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
                android:layout_width="57sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/toggleSun"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/toggleSun"
                android:textOn="@string/Mon"
                android:textOff="@string/Mon"
                android:id="@+id/toggleMon"
                android:checked="false" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
                android:layout_width="55sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textOn="@string/Tue"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/toggleMon"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/toggleMon"
                android:textOff="@string/Tue"
                android:id="@+id/toggleTue"
                android:checked="false" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
                android:layout_width="55sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textOn="@string/Wed"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/toggleTue"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/toggleTue"
                android:textOff="@string/Wed"
                android:id="@+id/toggleWed"
                android:checked="false" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
                android:layout_width="55sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textOn="@string/Thu"
                android:textOff="@string/Thu"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/toggleWed"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/toggleWed"
                android:id="@+id/toggleThurs"
                android:checked="false" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
                android:layout_width="55sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textOn="@string/Fri"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/toggleThurs"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/toggleThurs"
                android:textOff="@string/Fri"
                android:id="@+id/toggleFri"
                android:checked="false" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
                android:layout_width="55sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/toggleFri"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/toggleFri"
                android:textOn="@string/Sat"
                android:textOff="@string/Sat"
                android:id="@+id/toggleSat"
                android:checked="false" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.20">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT:**

Well...the best solution in your way it's use `weight` like percents, that is, you can divide your layouts in parts (weight using %), in my example, you can see three parts:

1. `android:layout_weight="0.20"` (20%)
2. `android:layout_weight="0.60"` (60%)
3. `android:layout_weight="0.20"` (20%)

TOTAL: 100%

If you put `weight tag`, you must to put your `height or width` to `0dp` (depends of ur layout its vertical or horizontal).

Then if you want put your button just below the toggle buttons, you only need enlarge the last part, that is, enlarge the button Layout and decrease the second one, in total 100%.

For example, you could prove:

1. `android:layout_weight="0.20"` (20%)
2. `android:layout_weight="0.20"` (20%)
3. `android:layout_weight="0.60"` (60%)

You can put too a "invisible" layout using a `FrameLayout` with a weight tag.

Comment: How can I increase the height of the `timePicker`?

Comment: You can use weights inside  the first `LinearLayout`.

Comment: What if I want to place the button just below the toggle button?

Comment: Paint exactly what do you need (use paint, photoshop, real paper....), update your question with the image, I'll provide you the sollution and I'll explain you later whatever you want to know to learn it.

Comment: Edited. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Height of the `RelativeLayout` that contains `ToggleButton`s must be `wrap_content`. And you cannot use `layout_centerVertical` and `layout_centerHorizontal` attributes with `LinearLayout`.

Edit: I suggest using this, instead of your RelativeLayout. Try to avoid using numbers as much as you can.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:weightSum="7">

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleSun"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:checked="false"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textOff="Sun"
            android:textOn="Sun" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleMon"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:checked="false"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textOff="Mon"
            android:textOn="Mon" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleTue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:checked="false"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textOff="Tue"
            android:textOn="Tue" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleWed"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:checked="false"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textOff="Wed"
            android:textOn="Wed" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleThurs"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:checked="false"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textOff="Thu"
            android:textOn="Thu" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleFri"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:checked="false"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textOff="Fri"
            android:textOn="Fri" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleSat"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:checked="false"
            android:textOff="Sat"
            android:textOn="Sat" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you use `fill_parent` for a layout, It would fill the available space in the screen with that layout. `wrap_content` uses only the space that layout needs.

Comment: How about the button ?

Comment: It is the same for a button as well. You should check out [this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-wrap_content-and-fill_parent-example/) link and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432763/whats-the-difference-between-fill-parent-and-wrap-content) link for understanding layout attributes completely.

Answer (score 1):

use layout as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Alarm"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <View android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_width="340sp" android:layout_height="2dp" android:background="#c0c0c0" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Repeat"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

        <ToggleButton

            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_width="55sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textOn="@string/Sun"
            android:textOff="@string/Sun"
            android:checked="false"
            android:id="@+id/toggleSun" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
            android:layout_width="57sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/toggleSun"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/toggleSun"
            android:textOn="@string/Mon"
            android:textOff="@string/Mon"
            android:id="@+id/toggleMon"
            android:checked="false" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
            android:layout_width="55sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textOn="@string/Tue"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/toggleMon"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/toggleMon"
            android:textOff="@string/Tue"
            android:id="@+id/toggleTue"
            android:checked="false" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
            android:layout_width="55sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textOn="@string/Wed"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/toggleTue"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/toggleTue"
            android:textOff="@string/Wed"
            android:id="@+id/toggleWed"
            android:checked="false" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
            android:layout_width="55sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textOn="@string/Thu"
            android:textOff="@string/Thu"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/toggleWed"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/toggleWed"
            android:id="@+id/toggleThurs"
            android:checked="false" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
            android:layout_width="55sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textOn="@string/Fri"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/toggleThurs"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/toggleThurs"
            android:textOff="@string/Fri"
            android:id="@+id/toggleFri"
            android:checked="false" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
            android:layout_width="55sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/toggleFri"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/toggleFri"
            android:textOn="@string/Sat"
            android:textOff="@string/Sat"
            android:id="@+id/toggleSat"
            android:checked="false" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think about Linear Layout. 
Use `Linear Layout`instead of `Relative Layout`
And You Can use `Layout:weight`for alignment